# Is there a way we can share Redux states between React and React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, webview

We have a React Native application for mobile platform and a React application for the web we are using redux for state management in both the platforms we are thinking of using webviews in react native that will be served locally from react bundle from inside the APK I want to check whether or not it is possible to connect the reducer states between react native and the react local bundled components via window.postmessage when communicating via the WebView.

Is it theoretically possible but not viable is also something we are looking at because we don't want to maintain an application just for the sake of reusing it.

Some of the links i am following for this use case. This is more of a is it possible question please let me know from where to start.

https://github.com/blankg/rn-webview-bridge-sample-new/blob/master/android/app/src/main/assets/index.html

https://medium.com/capriza-engineering/communicating-between-react-native-and-the-webview-ac14b8b8b91a

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions we built also had the same requirement.

As per my knowledge, we cannot maintain a single redux store for both the applications i.e mobile and the web as those are 2 different clients separated from each other.

But still, you can communicate with each client when loading the webpages via webviews. The approach we took is sending data via URL params. And by using routings from reactJS to extract data and render the web page according to requirement interpreted by parameters.

```
<WebView 
    source={{ uri: 'https://m.domain.com/true/sv-FI/updateDetails' }} 
/>;
```

- `false` is to indicate url is requesting from a webview
- `sv-FI` is to say that react-native app's localization is set to Swedish (Finland). so react app serves Swedish translated web page
- ....rest of the parameters.

and also for sure, you may have limitations in this approach.

links that might be useful for you
- [How To Pass Multiple Route Parameters in a React URL Path](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-pass-multiple-route-parameters-in-a-react-url-path-4b919de0abbe)

Comment: So basically you are saying that we cannot use react redux connect to the state across RN and react. Also in this way you have mentioned the state will be in react as well as RN (if need be ) this is what i infered. Also all the logic of getting data will be managed by react from within inside the webview . Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: yes, you are correct. you need to maintain 2 redux stores in react app and RN app. and communication can be done via url parameters to pass the required RN app states to react app